# git p4 - Author of file changes are overwritten by user who integrated file

Tags: git, perforce, git-p4

I am converting my Perforce depot into a git repo by using **git p4**. With the help of answers in other questions I got it managed to copy over the history and integrations successfully.

Unfortunately the line history in files only refers to the person that made the integrate to the `master` branch, and not from where it came from. Example:

```
//depot/main/foo.txt
//depot/branch1/foo.txt
```

A user `foo` modifies foo.txt in `branch1`. Another user with the name `admin` performs the integrate to `main/foo.txt`.

In the file history of `main.txt` it states that `admin` performed the modification, but actually it was `foo`. Is there any way to activate this backtrace to distinguish between committer and author of modifications?

Comment: In Perforce you do this via commands like `changes -i` and `annotate -I`.  I don't think `git p4` preserves all of the merge history in a form where that author information is still available.

Comment: Oh, what a bummer! :-( thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using branch detection? That might work because the integration would be converted to a "tag" only and no new files are created.

Comment: I used “—branch-detect” and it detects the branches but integrates still are set as the author who made the integrate